# Display certain HTML in an Automatically generated PHP page?

Tags: php, mysql, html, database, auto-generate

How can I display a certain HTML code in a php generated page.

For example, php will automatically display the name and category of an item, yet I want to add custom pictures to this generated page. Is there any way to do this without creating a separate HTML page to include into the generated page?

I'm hoping for something like a database entry where to add the html part to display. Is it possible?

ps. Sorry if I didn't express my idea in a completely understandable way.

Comment: How is the PHP generating the rest of the page? Is this in something like wordpress or something? Is this your code or are you modifying other code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the image URLs just like you are storing the names and categories. Then you would just do something like:

```
<span id="name"><?= $name ?></span>
<span id="category"><?= $category ?></span>
<img src="<?= $image ?>" />
```

Maybe you need to clarify - why do you need different HTML for each page, if the only thing changing are the images?

Keep in mind here I use `<?= $foo ?>` which is generally considered bad practice, and is just shorthand for `<?php echo $foo; ?>`.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the PHP in your HTML:

```
<h1>My Test</h1>
<?= $myCategory; ?> - <?= $myItem; ?>
<img src ="mySource" alt="myImg" width="15" height="15" />
```

This also works for your HTML in your Database:

```
<p><?= $myDatabaseHTMLContent ?></p>
```

Cheers,
Max

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php 
  //Your php code 
 ?>
   <img src="" />
 <?php
   //Your php code 
 ?>
```

You can put html in a php file, like the example above.